# array with a few elements to hash with a condigions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an example of an array, like a :

```
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Crew id: 3797, leader_id: 425, time_leaving: "2000-01-01 03:04:00", time_arriving: "2000-01-01 19:08:00"]
```

And i want to convert it to hash, like a:

```
time = time_arriving -time_leaving  # time = 18.06.00 

{3797 => 18.06.00 }
```

How to do it? Help me, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there is an `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation` not a "pure" array. So you can use Active Record and get something like your expected output with SQL:

```
Crew.pluck(:id, 'time_leaving - time_arriving').to_h
# {1=>"23:59:59.991133"}
```

`pluck` returns an array of arrays, containing the id and the dates difference accordingly, then you can use `to_h` to convert that to a hash.

Comment: thx, but at another hashes value is nil, how i can change nil to 0 ?

Comment: You can use any condition to check that, but, you can't have a hash with duplicated keys, are you sure that's the way you need to do it?